# Spring statemachine redis - configure ttl

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-statemachine

I'm using **`spring statemachine`** in my spring boot application. In this application I have configured `redis` as `StateMachineRuntimePersister` in this way:

```
@Bean
public StateMachineRuntimePersister<?, ?, String> stateMachineRuntimePersister(RedisStateMachineRepository redisStateMachineRepository) {
    return new RedisPersistingStateMachineInterceptor<>(redisStateMachineRepository);
}
```

And I pass above persister to my `StateMachinService`.

With this configuration, everything is working and states saved in redis. But I want to set `ttl(time to live)` for data in redis. Is there any way to achieve this?